# Localization and OAuth dialog

Tags: localization, facebook-oauth

I have a desktop application. For authentication I am using the Client-side Flow as described in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication.

How do I specify locale when I request the OAuth dialog such as:

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?locale=en_US...

But when I do this, the locale value is not carried through the redirect.

(Before OAuth, I used locale= when requesting the login dialog using Connect.)

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Comment: Forgot to add I am not using any sdk.  Just C++ and HTTP.  I use an embedded browser.

Comment: Ok.  I'll assume that the translation links provided (below the login) are the only means of translation and that I cannot control it through the use of query items.